# Can I assign members to subscription packages without payment transactions?

Tags: devdemon, subscriptions

Can I assign members to subscription packages without payment transactions? So maybe a visitor to the site would buy a package through my own separate shopping cart, which would send an email to an admin. That admin would then log into the EE control panel and assign that member to the subscription package he asked for. But this would bypass the payment gateways built into the Subscriptions add-on.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there's no manual configuration for Subscriptions as of now.